# Вызов экрана настроек разрешений для приложения

Tags: android

В процессе работы над приложением столкнулся с тем что необходимо проверять разрешения для приложения и хотел бы добавить кнопку по которой пользователь сможет сразу перейти в раздел разрешений для приложения или хотя бы на экран "О приложении". Видел что это реализовано в некоторых приложениях, но не смог найти решения на просторах гугла =( Подскажите как можно это сделать.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день.

Сразу перейти в раздел пермишенов нельзя, но, тем не менее, можно перейти на экран "О приложении". Для этого можно использовать код:

```
private static void startAppDetailsActivity(final Activity context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", context.getPackageName(), null);
    intent.setData(uri);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```